# Создание экземпляров структуры из нескольких массивов

Tags: массивы, swift, структуры, arraylist, struct

Столкнулся с небольшой проблемой, прошу вашей помощи так как не могу понять свою ошибку (недавно начал изучать Swift).

Есть **структура** Human с 3мя параметрами: Name, Surname и Age (два String и один Int).
Есть 3 массива: nameArray, surnameArray и ageArray.
Я указал в nameArray 4 имени, в surnameArray 4 фамилии, в Age 6 возрастов.

Нужно через цикл создать 6 случайных людей структуры Human, при этом name и surname берутся случайно и повторяться не должны. 
Значение age так же берется случайно из своего массива, и так же без дубликатов.

Я вроде все сделал, ошибок никаких нет, но почему то цикл вообще не выдаёт никаких результатов :(

```
struct Human {
var name: String
var surname: String
var age: Int
}

let nameA = ["Nik", "Max", "Oliver", "Ted"]
let surnameA = ["Jackson", "Grifeen", "Boatlord", "Nicklson"]
let ageA = [20, 25, 27, 60, 80, 13]

 // создаем человека
var humans: [Human] = []

func createHuman() {
for _ in 1...6 {
    if nameA.isEmpty == false && surnameA.isEmpty == false {
                        let human = Human(name: nameA.randomElement()!,
                                            surname: surnameA.randomElement()!,
                                            age: ageA.randomElement()!)

        humans.append(human)
        }
    }
}
```

Создайте TableView приложение, в котором должен отображаться список людей с рандомными именами, фамилиями и возрастом. Создайте для этого отдельные массивы для имен,фамилий,возраста

Выбирая конкретную персону из списка должен открыть экран с деталями: Имя/Фамилия/Возраст

-Создайте модель данных Human со всеми необходимыми свойствами. В качестве модели определите структуру
-Для создания экземпляра Human() используйте рандомные элементы соответствующих массивов  
-Для отображения данных в вашем приложении используйте значения экземпляра Human()  
-Все значения для каждого человека должны быть уникальными, никаких дубликатов

P.S: код добавил, но здесь нет проверки на дубликаты
P.P.S: добавил все условия для задачи

Comment: Покажите ваш код.

Comment: Код добавил, извиняюсь что сразу не додумался сделать этого :(

Comment: Вам обязательно через структуры это решать, а не через классы?

Comment: Добавил описание задачи - есть ощущение что я неправильно её понял. А так да, именно структура

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовать билдер как паттерн может и хорошая идея, но делать енумы со всеми доступными значениями - нет. Воспользуйтесь сэтами.

```
struct Human {
    var name: String
    var surname: String
    var age: Int
}

struct FullName {
    let name: String
    let surname: String
}

extension FullName: Hashable {
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(name)
        hasher.combine(surname)
    }
}

let nameA = ["Nik", "Max", "Oliver", "Ted"]
let surnameA = ["Jackson", "Grifeen", "Boatlord", "Nicklson"]
let ageA = [20, 25, 27, 60, 80, 13]

// создаем человека
var humans: [Human] = []

func createHuman() {
    var availableFullNameSet = Set<FullName>()
    for name in nameA {
        for surname in surnameA {
            availableFullNameSet.insert(FullName(name: name, surname: surname))
        }
    }

    var ageSet = Set<Int>(ageA)

    let count = 6
    assert(availableFullNameSet.count >= count)
    assert(ageSet.count >= count)

    for _ in 1...count {
        let fullName = availableFullNameSet.popFirst()!
        let age = ageSet.popFirst()!
        humans.append(Human(name: fullName.name, surname: fullName.surname, age: age))
    }
}
```

Но если вы до последнего хотите использовать только массивы, то сделайте так

```
func createHuman() {
    var availableFullNameA = [FullName]()
    for name in nameA {
        for surname in surnameA {
            availableFullNameA.append(FullName(name: name, surname: surname))
        }
    }

    var availableAgeA = ageA

    let count = 6
    assert(availableFullNameA.count >= count)
    assert(availableAgeA.count >= count)

    for _ in 1...count {
        let fullNameIndex = Int.random(in: 0..<availableFullNameA.count)
        let fullName = availableFullNameA[fullNameIndex]
        availableFullNameA.remove(at: fullNameIndex)

        let ageIndex = Int.random(in: 0..<availableAgeA.count)
        let age = availableAgeA[ageIndex]
        availableAgeA.remove(at: ageIndex)

        humans.append(Human(name: fullName.name, surname: fullName.surname, age: age))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем, у вас должно получиться примерно следующее:

Я использую классы, но для структур будет примерно так же.
Создаете модель человека:

```
import Foundation

class Human: NSObject {
    var name: String
    var surname: String
    var age: Int

    init(withName name: String, withSurname surname: String, withAge age: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.age = age
    }
}
```

Потом создаете отдельный класс, который будет отвечать за создание таких человеков.

```
import Foundation

class HumanBuilder: NSObject {
    static let sharedHumanBuilder = HumanBuilder()

    enum availableNames: String {
        case Nik = "Nik"
        case Max = "Max"
        case Oliver = "Oliver"
        case Ted = "Ted"

        static func getRandomName() -> String {
            let randomIndex = Int.random(in: 0 ..< 3)

            switch randomIndex {
            case 0:
                return availableNames.Nik.rawValue
            case 1:
                return availableNames.Max.rawValue
            case 2:
                return availableNames.Oliver.rawValue
            case 3:
                return availableNames.Ted.rawValue
            default:
                return availableNames.Nik.rawValue
            }
        }
    }

    enum availableSurnames: String {
        case Jackson = "Jackson"
        case Griffin = "Griffin"
        case Boatlord = "Boatlord"
        case Nicklson = "Nicklson"

        static func getRandomSurname() -> String {
            let randomIndex = Int.random(in: 0 ..< 3)

            switch randomIndex {
            case 0:
                return availableSurnames.Jackson.rawValue
            case 1:
                return availableSurnames.Griffin.rawValue
            case 2:
                return availableSurnames.Boatlord.rawValue
            case 3:
                return availableSurnames.Nicklson.rawValue
            default:
                return availableSurnames.Jackson.rawValue
            }
        }
    }

    enum availableAges: Int {
        case thirteen = 13
        case twenty = 20
        case twentyFive = 25
        case twentySeven = 27
        case sixty = 60
        case eighty = 80

        static func getRandomAge() -> Int {
            let randomIndex = Int.random(in: 0 ..< 5)

            switch randomIndex {
            case 0:
                return availableAges.thirteen.rawValue
            case 1:
                return availableAges.twenty.rawValue
            case 2:
                return availableAges.twentyFive.rawValue
            case 3:
                return availableAges.twentySeven.rawValue
            case 4:
                return availableAges.sixty.rawValue
            case 5:
                return availableAges.eighty.rawValue
            default:
                return availableAges.thirteen.rawValue
            }
        }
    }

    func createHumansCollection(withSize size: Int) -> [Human] {
        var humans = [Human]()
        for _ in 1...size {
            let human = Human.init(withName: availableNames.getRandomName(), withSurname: availableSurnames.getRandomSurname(), withAge: availableAges.getRandomAge())
            humans.append(human)
        }

        return humans
    }
}
```

Далее вызываете этот билдер и говорите ему создать шесть человеков.

```
let humans = HumanBuilder.sharedHumanBuilder.createHumansCollection(withSize: 6)
```

Все, минимальная задача выполнена. Если вам надо, чтобы человеки еще и не повторялись, то в билдере, перед тем как добавлять элемент в коллекцию, его надо сравнить со всеми уже существующими человеками. Можете написать под это еще один метод в билдере либо перегрузить isEquals в модели.

Comment: Спасибо, всю запись сам я понял, но нам нужна работа через 4 массива)

Comment: да без разницы, используете массивы вместо enum-ов, будет так же.

Comment: @Roraks, Вы в своем вопросе так и не ответили, где вы метод createHuman вызываете.

Comment: Да, теперь я понял свою ошибку. Я делал в правильном направлении но забыл о некоторых деталях в методе (сделать возврат к массиву структуры и return). Сейчас все получилось! Попозже постараюсь доделать проверку на дубликаты и выложить сюда

Comment: Да уж, теперь я столкнулся с такими вещами как cell.textLabel?.text и тд, так как это массив структур